# How to cure Frog's curse?

Tags: chrono-trigger

I'm replaying Chrono Trigger. My understanding is that you can cure Frog's curse, and see him in human form during the ending.

According to the FAQs and walkthroughs, I need to

> kill Magus at North Cape,

which i have done. And yet, when I beat the game, Frog still remains an amphibian.

What else do I need to do to cure Frog?

(In case it matters, I'm running the Playstation port, on an actual Playstation. (Not a PS2/3 or emulator))

Answer (score 6):

I don't think the requirements of this have changed on any of the platforms.

Did you specifically initiate the event with Frog in your party at the time?

If you have Frog in your party when you head to the North Cape, there will be conversation about the curse. Consequently, Frog will fight the battle *on his own*. If you win in this scenario, then it should result in the curse being broken for the ending.

Comment: Yes, I did. I had Frog fight solo.

Comment: @Sean Hum. I'm unaware of any other requirements - some places *say* that using the bucket versus crashing into Epoch to fight Lavos affect this part of the ending (saying that you should use the bucket), but I don't recall that having an effect when I played and different sources contest this. I might suggest giving that a shot, otherwise, I'm unaware that anything else would affect it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps according to this Wikia, I haven't done these endings in ages but all of this sounds correct.

> Ending 1e: Revenge for Cyrus
>
> Method: When Frog and Magus face each other on the North Cape, either
>   fight and kill him or spare Magus' life
>
> In the canon ending, Frog spares Magus' life, as killing him will not
>   return Cyrus. Magus joins the group for the rest of the adventure,
>   leaving at the end to search for his sister. However, if you choose to
>   fight Magus in a one-on-one battle and defeat him, Magus' spell that
>   transformed him into a half-human / half-fiend will wear off, but not
>   until the end of the game.
>
> After defeating Lavos, Magus' magic wears off, and Frog turns back
>   into Glenn, who is a tall, muscular man. This is because he aged ten
>   years while in his fiendish form. He bids farewell to the others,
>   preparing to return to the Middle Ages. Lucca and Marle use the
>   opportunity to remark on how handsome Glenn truly is, wishing that he
>   could stay around longer.
>
> This does not change the ending of the game.

For a complete list (of all the endings), check out the source below.

Source: http://chrono.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Chrono_Trigger_endings

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you don't need to kill Magus to cure Frog. I know that every source seems to say that you DO need to kill Magus in order to bring about the "Frog turns human" ending, but in my own game, I spared Magus, he was alive and appeared in the game ending sequence, and in the same sequence, Frog was also turned human. I'm not sure if this was a glitch or the direct result of certain very specific things I did with the character Frog during the game, but all I know is that I spared Magus, and Frog was cured regardless.